# Can I transfer my XBOX 360 GTA character to my PS3?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Is this possible? Or only for next gen?

If it is possible, does anyone know how to make it work? I really don't want to have to start over.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't transfer cross platform on the same generation (You can only go PS3 -> Xbox One, or XBox360 -> PS4)

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible because games on different platforms are different "builds" of the game. It's the same reason why you can't play multiplayer with people on PS3 while on an Xbox.

Comment: Not entirely true. You cant xfer betseen xbox and pc, either, but they are compatible for multiplayer to an extent